# Process.Start cmd results in "is not recognized"

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, command-line

When launching an application directly, the application is launched, but when launched through `cmd` - it's not.

For example:

Works:

```
Process.Start("firefox");
```

Doesn't work:

```
Process.Start(
    new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd",
        Arguments = "/k firefox"
    });
```

I've tried setting `UseShellExecute` to true, but to no avail. I still get:

> 'firefox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

So, yes, I can specify the complete path. But is there a way to avoid that? Or in other words - what's the difference between the two that makes the second fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I guess you are probably looking for the `start` command:

```
Process.Start(
    new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd",
        Arguments = "/k start firefox"
    });
```

As a tip, simply run "**firefox**" in a command prompt -> you'd get the same error message.

Comment: Thanks. (About the "tip" - Yes, I know, that's basically the question :) )